# Delete records with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to exclude duplicate records in the `bidding_price` column with the following conditions:

Table: `bid_account`

Columns to check:

> `id` = PRIMARY KEY
>  `auction_id` = ID of each product
>   `bidding_price` = inserted value (this must be checked for duplicity for each product)
>  
>   `bid_flag` = must always equal the value of: **'d'**
>  `bidding_type` = must always equal the value of:: **'s'**

It will always exist equal records in the `bidding_price` column, which it can not have is equal records with the same product ID (`auction_id`).

Example of how it should not have:

> **auction_id** | **bidding_price**
>   *------10------------0.02
>
>   ------10------------0.02
>
>   ------11------------0.02
>
>   ------11------------0.02*

The correct would be:

> **auction_id** | **bidding_price**
>   *------10------------0.02
>
>   ------11------------0.02*

I tried with the following command:

```
DELETE ba
    FROM bid_account ba JOIN
         (SELECT ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id
          FROM bid_account ba2
          WHERE ba2.bid_flag = 'd' AND ba2.bidding_type = 's'
          GROUP BY ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price
         ) ba2
         ON ba2.auction_id = ba.auction_id AND
            ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price AND
            ba2.max_id < ba.id
WHERE ba.bid_flag = 'd' AND ba.bidding_type = 's' AND ba.auction_id = ba2.auction_id
```

The problem is that it deleted multiple records that it should not delete, did not do the validations correctly. How can I do it?

Comment: how about doing`delete from table where id in (select id ....)` this will give you certainty

Comment: If this is a constraint you would want to always have then you should use a trigger before insert to enforce the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID is your *PRIMARY KEY* in the table, so you can get `MAX(id)` to be your 
Reservation ID,then use `NOT IN` to delete by ID without `MAX(id)`

You can try this.

```
DELETE ba FROM bid_account ba
WHERE ba.id NOT IN
(
  SELECT max_id FROM 
    (
      SELECT auction_id, bidding_price, MAX(id) max_id
      FROM bid_account 
      WHERE bid_flag = 'd' AND bidding_type = 's'
      GROUP BY auction_id, bidding_price
    ) t
)
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f2e5/1*

**EDIT**

If you want to get lowest-value ID you could use `MIN(id)` in the subquery in the where clause

```
DELETE ba FROM bid_account ba
WHERE ba.id NOT IN
(
  SELECT min_id FROM 
    (
      SELECT auction_id, bidding_price, MIN(id) min_id
      FROM bid_account 
      WHERE bid_flag = 'd' AND bidding_type = 's'
      GROUP BY auction_id, bidding_price
    ) t
)
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffe92/1*

Comment: @D-Shih...Perfect, and how can I keep only the lowest-value ID? I noticed that it he keep the highest value ID there.

Comment: @Wendler If you want to get lowest-value ID you could use `MIN(id)` in the subquery in the where clause. You can see my edit answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The below statement should give you all the records that you need.

```
SELECT ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id
FROM bid_account ba2
WHERE ba2.bid_flag = 'd' AND ba2.bidding_type = 's'
GROUP BY ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price;
```

A not-in clause should give you all the records that you don't need.
So, delete from bid_account where id not in (#sub query to fetch required ids#) and ba.bid_flag = 'd' AND ba.bidding_type = 's'; should delete the duplicate records.

Comment: You need to add `HAVING COUNT(ba2.id) > 1` otherwise you could end  up deleting one record on it's own (which isn't a duplicate).

Comment: No, the above query returns everything that you need. Hence I have mentioned a Not-IN clause, which deletes everything that you don't need. If its a record which is on its own (no duplicate), it will be returned by the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it by using your PRIMARY KEY: ID.
It is used to uniquely identify the record for delete action.
See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603d56/1

It makes use of selecting the ID within a subquery(selecting it twice will AVOID the error:  target table cannot be specified for update).  The subquery is similar to your query and it selects the id that will be retained. Using NOT IN means delete the rest of the rows not equal to these ids in the subquery.

```
delete e.*
from bid_account e
where e.id not in (
select id from (
    select a.id
    from bid_account a
    join bid_account b
    on a.auction_id=b.auction_id
    and a.bidding_price=b.bidding_price
    and a.bid_flag=b.bid_flag
    and a.bidding_type=b.bidding_type
    where a.bid_flag='d' and a.bidding_type='s'
    and a.id < b.id) tt);
```